# Detect focus on HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

As when using youtube, if you click on "play" or "pause" the focus is on the video and using `spacebar` will pause or play the video.

In the same line, I would like to prevent the `spacebar` action after playing on a HTML5 video. 
To do so I was trying to detect the focused element, but it seems the video element doesn't get the `focus` event in the same way.

I tried using jQuery for it:

```
$(':focus');
```

And plain Javascript:

```
document.activeElement
```

None with success.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you are trying to prevent space from interacting with the video, I would suggest adding an event handler on the video that detects if the sapce bar has been pressed, and ignores it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an event listener to your video element and on play event focus some other(focusable) element on the page e.g a dummy button which does nothing

```
var video=document.getElementById("MyVideo");

video.addEventListener('play', function () { 
  document.getElementById("myDummyButton").focus();
});
```

this will take away the focus from your video element to the dummy button as soon as the video is played. You can also do the same for pause event.

And carefully place the button close to your video element because focussing it will cause the page to scroll if it is placed somewhere below in the page off the screen.
Also keep in mind that all types of elements are not focussable.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this:

```
document.getElementByID("video").onfocus = function(){}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a key event handler so you can filter out key events on the video element.

```
video.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
  /* check the key you don't want and if hit call: */
  evt.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

You can force the element to take focus by specifying a tabindex attribute if it doesn't already

```
<video tabindex="1" /* etc. */ ></video>
```